# how to add toggleClass in react js

Tags: reactjs

I having List of li, that li is repeating in map function each li having same click event, when i click on current li i need to add active class for that li. when click again the same li i need to remove the active class, the class should be remove when i click the same li only. like that i can add multi active class for li.

```
this.state = {
        activeKey:""
}
filterClick(e, i){
    this.setState({
        activeKey: i
    });
}

this.state.data.map(function(el,i){
return <li className={self.state.activeKey === i ? "fliter-row active" : "fliter-row"} key={i} onClick={self.handleClick.bind(self)}>
        <div>List</div>
    </li>
});
```

this is my code i tried so for

Comment: active class can be present with multiple li's at the same time ??

Comment: no when i click the li for current li only want to add active class

Comment: toggleClass is an correct example in jquery. same way i want to do in react js

Comment: i will write style for current li

Comment: can any one help me?